# Error while debugging C program in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, gdb, malloc

When I am debugging c program using `gdb` in Eclipse I am getting this error
**"Can't find a source file at "/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/csu/libc-start.c"**
.

I observed this error comes when I am using `malloc` to allocate memory.
But when debug and press step into it got skipped.

When I am running simple program where `malloc` is used still same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your debugger is looking for the source code for `malloc`.  When debugging, you generally don't need to go into the source for system/library functions, as bugs are most likely not there.  Just step over those functions when debugging and you should be fine.